# get posts where relationship count is equel to post's attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model "Post" which has a field "daily" in the database.

```
$table->integer('daily'); // could be anything
```

The Model "Post" has a relationship to the model "Comments".

```
public function comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}

public function completed() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->completed();
}
```

Comments model

```
public function scopeCompleted($query) {
       return $query->....?
}
```

I want to get all user's posts where it's comments count are equal to the post's 'daily' field. For example: if the post's daily field is '5' and there are 5 comments to this posts, I want to see this post in the returned lists, otherwise don't return it.
I know I can get all of them and do it with loop, but I wanna know if there is any way to do this with eloquent only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $user=User::with('posts','posts.comments')
          ->whereHas('posts.comments',function ($query){
                  //if any additional filters
           },'=',DB::raw('posts.daily'))
    ->get();
```

or if not needed additional query then

```
$user=User::with('posts','posts.comments')
          ->whereHas('posts.comments',null,'=',DB::raw('posts.daily'))
          ->get();
```

Comment: "DB::raw('posts.daily')" returns 'posts.daily', a string, it doesn't get the value from the database for each post

Comment: yes, I have, it returns it as 'posts.daily'. I can provide the sql with some data later.

Comment: @CritingZ have you tested the the my sollution?if tested then can you mention what erorr or wrong result its showing so i can check again. if you provide sql with some data then i can verify from my end

Comment: @CritingZ it returns it as 'posts.daily' means ? i didnt understood what you mean by that

Comment: @CritingZ can you show sql generated by your code for my answer

Comment: "select * from `posts` where `posts`.`board_id` = 1 and `posts`.`board_id` is not null and (select count(*) from `comments` where `post`.`id` = `comments`.
`post_id`) = posts.daily" that's what it returns, 'posts.daily' is staying as a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234786/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-critingz).

Answer (score 0):

Got it working like this

```
public function scopeCompleted($query) {
     return $query->has('comments', '=', DB::raw('posts.comments'));
}
```